# RCP Command with object argument

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to call an RCP command in code, like this:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)window.getService(IHandlerService.class);
    handlerService.executeCommand(cmdID, null);
```

With considerably more code, I can call the command with a string argument by assembling a Parameterization object then building a `ParameterizedCommand` and so forth but Paramaterization  only allows for string values, and can't be subclassed.

What I really want to do is call the command with an object as a parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ParameterizedCommand.generateCommand()`. You can pass the command object (obtained from `ICommandService`) and the parameters in a map.

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm only getting a "cannot be cast to java.lang.String" exception if i try to add an object instead of a String.

Comment: I looked into this, it looks like you also need define a ParemeterValueConverter to converter your objects into Strings and back. I find that very impractical, tbh. You might be able to get away with using HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event) for some parameters.